# Почему не раздается интернет через wi-fi в ubuntu 18.4?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Делаю точку доступа wi-fi для раздачи интернета с ноутбука с ubuntu 18.04 на android телефон. Телефон видит точку доступа и подключается к ней но интернета на телефоне нету. Пробывал делать точку доступа как через графический интерфейс ubuntu так и используя create_ap, а также nmcli, но результат всегда один.
На ноутбук интернет приходит через ethernet кабель.
В настройках подключения ethernet задан статический ip и DNS предоставлены провайдером, а также для того чтобы интернет работал на ноутбуке запущена программа активатор (есть только под windows и запущена через wine) также предоставлена провайдером. 
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите на hostapd и dhcpd. Кроме того, нужно включить ip forwarding и MASQUERADE в iptables.

Comment: а как включить ip forwarding и MASQUERADE в iptables?

Comment: А на каком месте при поиске этого в гугле вы остановились?